# how to display dynamic content in a single page using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJs and for stackoverflow too,hope will get a solution for my problem here. I`m trying to display the details of an experiment(in the same page)based on the name of the experiment which is coming from the URL when the name is clicked(index.html). Here the problem is,when I click an experiment name,it is coming in the URL but not able to fetch  its details.Can anyone help me to solve.Here is my code.

//experiments.json

[
  {
      "sl_no" : "1",
      "name" : "BCD adders",
      "objective" : "It deals with the desinging of reversible BCD adders."
},
 {"sl_no" : "2",
      "name" : "Online Banking",
      "objective" : "It deals with the online Transactions."}
]

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html ng-app="experimentApp">

   <head>

   <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="main">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
       </div>
       <br>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

       <div>

         <ul ng-controller="ExperimentListCtrl">
          <li ng-repeat="experiment in experiments">

           <a href="#/{{experiment.name | encodeURI}}">

              <strong>{{experiment.sl_no}}. {{experiment.name}}</strong><br>
             </a>
          </li>
         </ul>
           <div ng-include="experiment-detail.html"></div>

      </div>
     </ul>
    </div>  
   </nav>
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

//controller.js

// create the module and name it experimentApp
    var experimentApp = angular.module('experimentApp', ['ngRoute']);

```
// configure our routes
  experimentApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     when('/:experimentName', {
            templateUrl : 'experiment-detail.html',
            controller  : 'ExperimentDetailCtrl'
        }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

experimentApp.factory('experiments', function($http){

```
    function getData(callback){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'experiments.json',
        cache: true
      }).success(callback);
    }

    return {
      list: getData,
      find: function(name, callback){
        getData(function(data) {
          var experiment= data.filter(function(entry){
            return entry.name === name;
          })[0];
          callback(experiment);
        });
      }
    };
  });

experimentApp.controller('ExperimentListCtrl', function ($scope, experiments){
    experiments.list(function(experiments) {
      $scope.experiments = experiments;
    });
  });

  experimentApp.controller('ExperimentDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams,
                                                              experiments){
    experiments.find($routeParams.experimentName, function(experiment) {
      $scope.experiment = experiment;
    });
  });

experimentApp.filter('encodeURI', function(){
    return window.encodeURI;
  });
```

//experiment-detail.html

```
 <div>
     <strong>{{experiment.sl_no}}. {{experiment.name}}</strong><br>
       </br></br>

     <strong>Aim :</strong>{{experiment.objective}}      
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the experiment.name only, so change :

```
experimentApp.filter('encodeURI', function(){
    return window.encodeURI;
});
```

to :

```
experimentApp.filter('encodeURI', function(stringToEncode){
    return encodeUri(stringToEncode);
});
```

Comment: It is not working for me.:-( if I made that change first page itself is not working. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What do you mean by first page? are you trying to show both _experiment.list.html_ and _experiment.details.html_?

Comment: If you want to show both you should ng-include the template or use the ui.router from Angular UI. What you really want to show is a nested state/page, and it is not easily achieved with ngRoute

Comment: ya exactly.I am getting the list of experiment names in experiment-list.html.So when I click a name in this page,I want to display the corresponding details without any change.

Comment: Where should I use ng-include? Can you please help me?

Comment: Using a controller is the simplest way, but it will not look like a different url. Use ui.router and read about nested states. I hope i've helped you somehow